# Prevent write to Firebase after back from offline [Android]

Tags: android, firebase

I understood that Firebase has the capability to store the data locally during offline, and perform write when the device is back online.

However I would like to disable this feature for some writes in my application, as I would like to prevent the users to spam the database. Thanks.

Comment: One answer below. But I'm not sure how the queue-of-pending-writes and the ability for users to spam the database are related. Can you can a piece of code that demonstrates the problem? Preferably with the actual data that you're worried about. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what this is and why it may allow us to help you better.

Answer (score 1):

According Frank, there is no way we can control the write queue. Thus, I decided to write a utility to check for network connection. The write will be only executed if there is a connection.

NetworkUtil.java:

```
public class NetworkUtil {

    private Context context;

    public NetworkUtil(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean hasNetwork() {
        ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo info = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info == null || !info.isConnected())
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

}
```

And I added this lines to my activity:

```
/* Check for network */
NetworkUtil networkUtil = new NetworkUtil(getApplicationContext());
boolean hasNetwork = networkUtil.hasNetwork();

if (hasNetwork)
    /* perform write to firebase */
```

Comment: That's just checking for network connectivity, but not if you really have internet connection. Will you ping google.com upon every write connection to find out?

Answer (score 0):

All writes are queued until there is a connection to the Firebase servers again. There is no API to control which writes are queued and which are not.

The only loophole to this is that [*transactions*](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) are currently not persisted to disk and thus will be lost when the application is restarted.

Comment: Thank you Frank. Really appreciate your feedback. Since there is no way we can control the writes in queue, I have decided to use ConnectivityManager to check the internet connection, the write will only be executed if there is a network.

Comment: In that case, also consider using Firebase's built-in connectivity indicator `.info/connected`. It is documented here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state. There are potentially other reasons why your app isn't connected to Firebase than just those detected by `ConnectivityManager`.

Comment: Has there been a change?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - The Firebase connectivity indicator that you mention doesn't get called in some Android devices when the connection is lost, although it is working great in some others. Is that a bug of Firebase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It is April 2019 now, is there any better way to "Prevent write to Firebase after back from offline" than checking for connection before any write operation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but there are [`purgeOutstandingWrites()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#public-void-purgeoutstandingwrites-) for Database

```
com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app).purgeOutstandingWrites();
```

and [`clearPersistence()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#public-taskvoid-clearpersistence-) for Firestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().clearPersistance();
```