# Firebase Database: apparently rules do not apply if client is offline?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Consider the following example:

I'm writing a value on a `test/` node, and I have set up a rule, that will allow the write, only if the "(new value) equals (old value + 1)", that is `newData.val() == data.val() + 1`

Let's say that the initial value of the `test/` node is `0`.

If the client goes **offline** and executes the following commands:

```
testRef.setValue(1);
testRef.setValue(2);
testRef.setValue(3);
testRef.setValue(4);
testRef.setValue(5);
```

Then when he goes back online, the value `5` will be written in the database, but I'm not sure I understand why, since `5 != 0 + 1`. I guess that this happens due to the caching of the previous values in the local database, but unfortunately that's not the result I am trying to achieve. I want the server to reject that value since it doesn't follow the rules of the database.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Or is there any other workaround so that I can implement the following:

`testRef.setValue(1);` **->** write value to local database **->** check if value follows the rules of the online database **->** if the value does not follow the rules or if we can't check that because we are offline, then delete the value from the local database

Answer (score 2):

I assume that for your question "offline" means the client has no connection.  In my testing, I simulated that by enabling Airplane Mode.

Firebase offline capabilities are described in the [user guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). One detail provided there that is important to your question is:

> The Firebase Realtime Database client automatically keeps a queue of
>   all write operations that are performed while your app is offline ...
>   When the app regains connectivity, all of the operations are sent to
>   the Firebase Realtime Database server.

You can see this behavior using the code below, which adds a completion listener to the `setValue()` calls. In my test, I put the device into Airplane Mode (offline), ran the code, and then disabled Airplane Mode to go back online.  A log message is generated for each `setValue()`, confirming that the write operations were queued and sent when a connection was re-established.  This explains why the writes satisfy your validation rule: the client does not send one write request with the final value 5, it sends five requests with the original incrementing values.

You can confirm that the rule works by running the test again without first resetting the value of `test` back to 0.  Each write will fail.

This code also demonstrates how the Firebase client handles changes made when the client is offline, and which are later rejected by security rules.  While offline, the change is made in the client cache and the `onDataChange()` callback fires with the new (unvalidated) value.  Later, when the client goes online and the change is rejected by the server, `onDataChange()` fires again with the previous value.

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: test=" + dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class));
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});

final DatabaseReference.CompletionListener completionListener =
        new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "setValue() Success");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "setValue() Failed " + databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    }
};

ref.setValue(1, completionListener);
ref.setValue(2, completionListener);
ref.setValue(3, completionListener);
ref.setValue(4, completionListener);
ref.setValue(5, completionListener);
```

Comment: Thanks, I can understand that, however personally I would like to have an option to remove the value from local cache if the rules cannot be validated, due to the lack of an Internet connection. The reason that I need that, is because I'm developing a collaboration app, and some nodes are accessible by more than 1 users. In any case, is there a workaround to remove the values from local cache, if there's no any Internet connection? Something like a timeout? (i.e. if the server is unreachable for 5 seconds, delete all pending writes / local values from cache.

Comment: AFAIK there is no API to delete pending writes.  See this answer from Firebaser FvP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34625545/4815718.  It may be that the best you can do is [monitor the connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) and only allow writes when connected.